# Put every N rows of input into a new column

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

In bash, given input

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
...
```

And `N` for example 5, I want the output

```
1  6  11
2  7  12
3  8  ...
4  9
5  10
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace 5 in following script with your number.

```
seq 20|xargs -n5| awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i,NR]=$i; }END{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {for(j=1;j<=NR;j++)printf a[i,j]" "; print "" }}'
```

output:

```
1 6 11 16 
2 7 12 17 
3 8 13 18 
4 9 14 19 
5 10 15 20
```

note `seq 20` above there is just for generating the number sequence for testing. You don't need it in your real work.

**EDIT**

as pointed out by sudo_O, I add an pure awk solution:

```
 awk -vn=5 '{a[NR]=$0}END{ x=1; while (x<=n){ for(i=x;i<=length(a);i+=n) printf a[i]" "; print ""; x++; } }' file
```

test

```
kent$  seq 20| awk -vn=5 '{a[NR]=$0}END{ x=1; while (x<=n){ for(i=x;i<=length(a);i+=n) printf a[i]" "; print ""; x++; } }'     
1 6 11 16 
2 7 12 17 
3 8 13 18 
4 9 14 19 
5 10 15 20 

kent$  seq 12| awk -vn=5 '{a[NR]=$0}END{ x=1; while (x<=n){ for(i=x;i<=length(a);i+=n) printf a[i]" "; print ""; x++; } }'     
1 6 11 
2 7 12 
3 8 
4 9 
5 10
```

Comment: @sudo_O thx for pointing it out, I didn't test on that case, now a pure awk one-liner added.

Comment: You can use `{1..12}` instead of `seq 12`.

Comment: @Kent depends on your skill :)

Answer (score 15):

Using a little known gem `pr`:

```
$ seq 20 | pr -ts' ' --column 4
1 6 11 16
2 7 12 17
3 8 13 18
4 9 14 19
5 10 15 20
```

Comment: It's only a gem if it can complete the job. You should test this with `seq 21` for example. As you'll see, you'll need some post processing in order to achieve the desired output. Otherwise the command above will fail without some modification.

Comment: @user19340357: I'm not convinced it achieves the desired results. Regardless, when researching how a command works, you should first take a look at the man page for that particular command. In this case, type: [man pr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pr) to see the man page for `pr`. Given that there's only three options passed to `pr` in this instance, is there a particular flag that isn't well documented that you need more explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it with `awk`:

```
awk -v n=5 '{ c++ } c>n { c=1 } { a[c] = (a[c] ? a[c] FS : "") $0 } END { for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print a[i] }'
```

Some simple testing:

```
seq 21 | awk -v n=5 '{ c++ } c>n { c=1 } { a[c] = (a[c] ? a[c] FS : "") $0 } END { for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print a[i] | "column -t" }'
```

Results:

```
1  6   11  16  21
2  7   12  17
3  8   13  18
4  9   14  19
5  10  15  20
```

And another:

```
seq 40 | awk -v n=6 '{ c++ } c>n { c=1 } { a[c] = (a[c] ? a[c] FS : "") $0 } END { for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print a[i] | "column -t" }'
```

Results:

```
1  7   13  19  25  31  37
2  8   14  20  26  32  38
3  9   15  21  27  33  39
4  10  16  22  28  34  40
5  11  17  23  29  35
6  12  18  24  30  36
```