# Convert one column into a new column every 5 rows (a numeric interval)

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I have a long column with lots of results from an analysis (as an .txt file, that I will read with R). Starting from the top, the first 5 rows are results that correspond to Sample1, the second chunk of 5 rows (rows 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10) correspond to Sample2, and so on from Sample1 to Sample57. So, I want to split that long column into 57 columns, to separate by sample.
Let's start with a smaller example to simplify the problem, just using the first two samples (so, the column has only 10 values, 5 for each). Let's say we have this column vector:

```
0.01
0.02
0.45
0.34
0.55
0.78
0.08
0.49
0.50
0.33
```

And I know the first 5 numbers correspond to Sample1, and the second to Sample2. I want to do this:

```
0.01 0.78
0.02 0.08
0.45 0.49
0.34 0.50
0.55 0.33
```

Overall, I want to transform that columnar vector into a matrix where each column is 5 rows long, and those numbers are in the same order as they were in the original vector. It's like if you had cut the original vector into 5row-long pieces, and paste them on the right in order. I've searched commands to split one column into multiple columns, but they used things that recognized character patterns. This is a different scenario.
Also I found this regarding the terminal [Put every N rows of input into a new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519372/put-every-n-rows-of-input-into-a-new-column) , but I was wondering if there is a way in R to do that, and maybe also simpler.

Is there a way to do this strictly every 5 rows?

Comment: If your data is in a data frame called `dtf`, you can add a column of sample numbers with `dtf$sample <- rep(1:(nrow(dtf)/5),each=5)` For most purposes, it may be a good idea to keep the data in a long format. unless you have a specific need for the wide matrix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes you can do following:

```
as.data.frame(split(data, 1:x))
```

where x = nr of rows / 5; in your example x = 2 as you have 10 observations

Answer (score 4):

We can use the `matrix` to construct this

```
matrix(df1[,1], nrow=5, ncol=2)
#    [,1] [,2]
#[1,] 0.01 0.78
#[2,] 0.02 0.08
#[3,] 0.45 0.49
#[4,] 0.34 0.50
#[5,] 0.55 0.33
```

---

If the number of rows are not a multiple of 5, then use either `spread` from `tidyverse` or `dcast` from `data.table` (`reshape2`)

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    mutate(i1 = rep(1:5, length.out=n()), grp = paste0("Col", cumsum(i1==1))) %>%
    spread(grp, Col1) %>%
    select(-i1)
#  Col1 Col2
#1 0.01 0.78
#2 0.02 0.08
#3 0.45 0.49
#4 0.34 0.50
#5 0.55 0.33
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.45, 0.34, 0.55, 0.78, 0.08, 
 0.49, 0.5, 0.33)), .Names = "Col1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```